# Angular 8: Change Height in Mat-form-field to Specific pixel number

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular8

How can I change height in `mat-form-field` with `appearance="outline"` to a specific height pixel number, 40px (or any required number from UX team in the future). I need to reduce the mat-form-field.

How can this be done?  What is the equation, or which part number can be modified to change to 40px?
-1.1? .75 , 133%,  Looking for some kind of function or math equation using answer below, or any other option which may work.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54762506/12425844

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-flex > .mat-form-field-infix { padding: 0.4em 0px !important;}
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-label-wrapper { top: -1.5em; }

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-can-float.mat-form-field-should-float .mat-form-field-label {
    transform: translateY(-1.1em) scale(.75);
    width: 133.33333%;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with height:40px; ? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-31dawx

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54760371/how-to-change-height-in-mat-form-field not work for you?

Comment: it didn't specify, already referenced in question

Comment: Are you trying to set to exactly 40px? could you explain what's wrong in the demo?

Comment: Do you mean 40px in total size of the element including the padding and the space for a hint/error, or do you mean that the outline should be 40px?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure exactly from where you want to cut, so I'll give you a few options and you can decide what and how much you want to cut in order to get the right size

To remove the margins from top and bottom

```
::ng-deep mat-form-field.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-wrapper {
    margin: 0;
}
```

To change the font size

```
mat-form-field {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

To remove the hint and errors (space in the bottom)

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper {
    display: none;
}
```

To change the padding (default is 1em for top and bottom)

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-infix {
    padding: .5em;
}
```

Note: if you choose to do the last one you will also have to change the `top` or `margin-top` of the `.mat-form-field-label` like this

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-label {
    top: ...;
    margin-top: ...;
}
```

Comment: doesn't work with Material v15. the components were basically re-written

Answer (score 2):

You can check it out here, on your project dependencies (@angular/material 8.2.3): `node_modules\@angular\material\_theming.scss`

Line ~ 4540 : @mixin **_mat-form-field-outline-label-floating** and **mat-form-field-outline-typography** :

```
// Used to make instances of the _mat-form-field-label-floating mixin negligibly different,
// and prevent Google's CSS Optimizer from collapsing the declarations. This is needed because some
// of the selectors contain pseudo-classes not recognized in all browsers. If a browser encounters
// an unknown pseudo-class it will discard the entire rule set.
$mat-form-field-outline-dedupe: 0;

// Applies a floating label above the form field control itself.
@mixin _mat-form-field-outline-label-floating($font-scale, $infix-padding, $infix-margin-top) {
  transform: translateY(-$infix-margin-top - $infix-padding + $mat-form-field-outline-dedupe)
  scale($font-scale);
  width: 100% / $font-scale + $mat-form-field-outline-dedupe;

  $mat-form-field-outline-dedupe: $mat-form-field-outline-dedupe + 0.00001 !global;
}

@mixin mat-form-field-outline-typography($config) {
  // The unit-less line-height from the font config.
  $line-height: mat-line-height($config, input);
  // The amount to scale the font for the floating label and subscript.
  $subscript-font-scale: 0.75;
  // The padding above and below the infix.
  $infix-padding: 1em;
  // The margin applied to the form-field-infix to reserve space for the floating label.
  $infix-margin-top: 1em * $line-height * $subscript-font-scale;
  // The space between the bottom of the .mat-form-field-flex area and the subscript wrapper.
  // Mocks show half of the text size, but this margin is applied to an element with the subscript
  // text font size, so we need to divide by the scale factor to make it half of the original text
  // size.
  $subscript-margin-top: 0.5em / $subscript-font-scale;
  // The padding applied to the form-field-wrapper to reserve space for the subscript, since it's
  // absolutely positioned. This is a combination of the subscript's margin and line-height, but we
  // need to multiply by the subscript font scale factor since the wrapper has a larger font size.
  $wrapper-padding-bottom: ($subscript-margin-top + $line-height) * $subscript-font-scale;
  // The amount we offset the label from the input text in the outline appearance.
  $outline-appearance-label-offset: -0.25em;

  .mat-form-field-appearance-outline {
    .mat-form-field-infix {
      padding: $infix-padding 0 $infix-padding 0;
    }

    .mat-form-field-label {
      top: $infix-margin-top + $infix-padding;
      margin-top: $outline-appearance-label-offset;
    }

    &.mat-form-field-can-float {
      &.mat-form-field-should-float .mat-form-field-label,
      .mat-input-server:focus + .mat-form-field-label-wrapper .mat-form-field-label {
        @include _mat-form-field-outline-label-floating(
                $subscript-font-scale, $infix-padding + $outline-appearance-label-offset,
                $infix-margin-top);
      }

      // Server-side rendered matInput with a label attribute but label not shown
      // (used as a pure CSS stand-in for mat-form-field-should-float).
      .mat-input-server[label]:not(:label-shown) + .mat-form-field-label-wrapper
      .mat-form-field-label {
        @include _mat-form-field-outline-label-floating(
                $subscript-font-scale, $infix-padding + $outline-appearance-label-offset,
                $infix-margin-top);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got you bro, Some easy Resolution is:

**add this on your css**

```css
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-flex {
height: 40px !important
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-infix {
padding-top: 1px !important;
}
```

**exaplained**

**Here you can control your mat-form-field height as you want.**

```css
 ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-flex {
    height: 40px !important
    }
```

**And with this bellow you can control your mat-form-field placeholder padding to match with the new height that you put.**

```css
  ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-infix {
    padding-top: 1px !important;
    }
```

I tried here and work fine

Answer (score 0):

you can add **panelClass** tp your **mat-form-field** like below:

**your component.html:**

```
 <mat-form-field panelClass="example-class"></mat-form-field>
```

and style it in global css file

**styles.scss:**

```
.example-class{

   height:40px
 }
```