# Angular Material: Styling mat-form-field inside mat-toolbar

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, angular-material

I'm trying to create a toolbar using Material's `mat-toolbar` with an input and select inside of it. For both, I am using Material's provided components (`mat-input` and `mat-select` respectively) inside of `mat-form-field`s as advised. My code looks like this:

```
<mat-toolbar>

    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-icon matPrefix>search</mat-icon>
      <input type="search" matInput placeholder="Search" />
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-select [(value)]="omitted">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let omitted of omitted" [value]="omitted.slug">
          {{ omitted.name }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

  </mat-toolbar>
```

At the moment, the input and select are too tall to completely fit in the toolbar. I am trying to style them to make them fit (by reducing `height`, `padding`, `margin`, etc.). However, Angular adds elements between `mat-form-field` and the contained elements. I am unable to style those elements from the component's Sass because of view encapsulation. So, even if I style everything immediately present in my template, the generated elements have heights, margins, and paddings that force the observed element to be outside of the toolbar.

I don't want to include a global style for those components because I don't want other `mat-form-field`s to get affected.

Turning off view encapsulation would essentially be the same thing as using global styling.

`::ng-deep` is deprecated so I can't use that.

I could style my own `input` and `select` from scratch, but then I lose out on the prebuilt styling that Material provides. Is there any way that I can style these Material components to fit in my toolbar?

Comment: I had the same issue, but then decided that going for https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview instead of a select in the toolbar would work for me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59865010/11294169 may help you, set the font-size of the container to be smaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similiar problem and I have solved it with wrapping component with a div and then style it in global stylesheet with this

```
.filters {
    mat-form-field {
        div.mat-form-field-flex {
            align-items: flex-end;
        }

        div.mat-form-field-prefix {
            padding-right: 12px !important;
        }
    }
}
```

In your case, you could add class (or id) to the toolbar or wrap the form field with a div and in order to encapsulate the rules you want.

Answer (score 9):

You can add `subscriptSizing="dynamic"` to mat-form-field. This will not reserve spacing for the subscript below the mat-form-field.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,` in the @Component decorator.

This will free the component from the restrains about styling. Keep in mind if you are using global styles you have to take care of the proper styling I will suggest using BEM for naming the CSS styles and not using generic naming.

More info - https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation

Answer (score 0):

I added the following rules in my global stylesheet to make the mat-form-field fit:

```
[the selector for the mat-form-field I wanted to affect]
    .mat-form-field-flex, .mat-form-field-label-wrapper
        padding-top: 0

    .mat-form-field-wrapper
        padding-bottom: 0

    .mat-form-field-underline
        bottom: 0

    .mat-form-field-infix
        border-top: 0
```