# How to reduce the height in mat-form-field?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-input

I need to reduce the height of the `mat-form-field` to 30px. (Not the just the inner element, the height of the whole mat-form-field. Any ideas?

This is a similar issue - [How to change height in mat-form-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54760371/how-to-change-height-in-mat-form-field), but none of the solutions worrked properly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the following CSS/SCSS code in the component's `.scss` or `.css` file or globally in the main global `.scss` or `.css` file  depends with your use case.

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-flex {
height: 40px !important
}
```

sets the top padding of the .mat-form-field-infix element to 1px and also uses the !important flag to override conflicting styles.

Note that the ::ng-deep selector is used before the CSS rules, which allows the styles to be applied globally to elements inside the component's template. It is considered a deprecated technique and should be avoided in favor of other component-level styling approaches.
If you need to center the text input you can also add this in your styling:

```
.mat-input-element {
  position: relative;
  top:  -0.3em; /* Adjust accordingly to keep placeholder/input text vertically centered. */
}
```

**Screenshot(Before)**

[image]

**Screenshot after applying the css/scss styling**

[image]