# Why will height not change for specific mat-form-field? (Angular 6)

Tags: html, css, angular

**Goal**: Make the height of a particular mat-form-field smaller (but still keep it positioned where it is, to the right of "Please Sign In"). 
It should take the minimum amount of space around the text value and dropdown arrow.

It currently looks like this:

[image: Width]

I want the lines on the box around it to be closer to the word English and the down arrow.
The box was created by adding: appearance="outline"

**Problem**: I was able to successfully change the width, but not the height.

**What I've tried**:

- I've gone through SO articles such as
  [How to change height in mat-form-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54760371/how-to-change-height-in-mat-form-field)
  and
  [Adjusting height of mat-form-field Angular Material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54102572/adjusting-height-of-mat-form-field-angular-material)
- I've tried adjusting the height itself (height: 40 px)
- I've tried minimizing the padding to make it look smaller
  (padding-top: -1.84375em; )
- I've tried changing it in Chrome Devtools but the text then aligns to
  the bottom of the box

**HTML**:

```
<div class="title-container">
    <mat-card-title class="text-center" i18n="@@MoVeSeLo_H1_1">
        Please Sign In
    </mat-card-title>
    <form [formGroup]="_siteForm">
        <mat-form-field class="language-field" appearance="outline">
            <mat-select (selectionChange)="doSomething($event)" [value]="languages[i]">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language">
                    {{language.viewValue}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.title-container {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

.language-field {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: -16px;
    width: 115px;
    height:40px;
    padding-top: -1.84375em;    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I got you bro, Some easy Resolution is:

**add this on your css**

```css
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-flex {
height: 40px !important
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-infix {
padding-top: 1px !important;
}
```

**exaplained**

**Here you can control your mat-form-field height as you want.**

```css
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-flex {
    height: 40px !important
    }
```

**And with this bellow you can control your mat-form-field placeholder padding to match with the new height that you put.**

```css
 ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-infix {
    padding-top: 1px !important;
    }
```

let me know with works to you

Comment: Thanks @Thiago for your response and explanation. It appears to be working but I am getting the warning: "::ngdeep is not a valid pseudo-element" , do you know why this would be?

Comment: Actually I noticed this is effecting everything else on the page, everything else got smaller. Even other pages got smaller that weren't touched.

Comment: @angleUr you need to use this only on the .css of the page u want. or it will really effect all the project, And yeah. all the .mat-form-field of the page will change

Comment: yes I only used it on that css page but it ended up affecting other pages. And yeah I only want it to affect that one mat form field, not any of the others. It is having weird affects. Ill play around with it a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Code in https://pxgeqykgapgy.angular.stackblitz.io/

HTML

```
<form class="example-container" [formGroup]="options" [style.fontSize.px]="getFontSize()">
    <mat-card-title class="text-center">
        Please Sign In
    </mat-card-title>
    <mat-form-field class="matselect" [color]="options.value.color">
        <mat-select formControlName="color">
            <mat-option value="primary">English</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="accent">Chinees</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="warn">Hindi</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

</form>
```

CSS

```
.example-container {
  display: flex;
}

.matselect{
    width: 115px !important;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}

::ng-deep .matselect .mat-form-field-underline {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I tried your CSS but it did not change the height.